# What data type or structure do I use to map a incoming file from an Angular 6 post to a Web Api Controller method?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

[image: Web API Controller method]
[image: C#Web Api Controller]
[image: C# Model]

[image: Front-End Debugger showing my object with File that I wanna send to the api.]
I am trying to upload a file on my front end in angular, post type call to my back end C# web api. It just comes through as null or an erroras you can see in the watch on my method. I am passing other information back with it that does come through. Its like data type mismatch or something similar.

Comment: In the first image you can see my problem, my Property File is NULL. I am uploading a file by way of a Api call.

Answer (score 0):

the correct type is object. As in 'public object File {get; set;}'
[image: filled out data tree showing object works]